# Pass value between activities and then back, method backpressed doesn´t work

Tags: android, webview, bundle

Im create an application that uses 3 Activities, in the first activity i type a word in a edit text, then i pass that value to another activity("second activity"), finally get that value and i pass to a webview to show a webpage, but when i try to return to the second activity from webview my app crashes , 
this is my code in first activity.

```
 Button _accion;
    EditText _capturaValor;
    String _guardarValor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _capturaValor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.valor);
        _accion = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAccion);

        _accion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _guardarValor = _capturaValor.getText().toString();
                if(_capturaValor.getText().length()!=0) {
                    Intent _webView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                    Bundle _pasarValor = new Bundle();
                    _pasarValor.putSerializable("guardarValor", _guardarValor);
                    _webView.putExtras(_pasarValor);
                    startActivityForResult(_webView, 0);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Escribe algo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And in my Second activity i have this code

```
Button _accion;
    EditText _capturaValor;
    String _guardarValor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        Bundle _obtenerValor = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String _valorRecuperado = (String)_obtenerValor.getSerializable("guardarValor");

        _capturaValor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.valor);
        _accion = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAccion);

        _capturaValor.setText(_valorRecuperado);
        _accion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _guardarValor = _capturaValor.getText().toString();
                Intent _webView = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webView.class);
                Bundle _pasarValor = new Bundle();
                _pasarValor.putSerializable("valor",_guardarValor);
                _webView.putExtras(_pasarValor);
                startActivityForResult(_webView,0);
            }
        });
    }
```

and Finally in my webView class i have this

```
 WebView _navegador;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        Bundle _obtenerValor = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String _valorRecuperado = (String)_obtenerValor.getSerializable("valor");

        _navegador = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        _navegador.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        _navegador.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
        _navegador.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        _navegador.loadUrl("https://www."+_valorRecuperado+".com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent _regresar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(_regresar);
    }
```

why when i tried to back to MainActivity2.class my app crashes?

Comment: get rid of `onBackPressed`. When you press on the back button the current Activity is finished and the one on the top of the stack is resumed

Answer (score 0):

As in `MainActivity2` you are calling,

`startActivityForResult(_webView,0);`

You have to implement `onActivityResult()` .

then in `WebView` Activity,

Just call, `finish()`. And if you want to success result from `webview` then write `setResult(0)`

then not required to start `MainActivity2` again. As `MainActivity2` is already available in Application stack.

So in `webView` just write like,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

**Now issue with your code,**

As you are starting `MainActivity2` again from webview activity,

in your MainActivity2's `onCreate()`

```
Bundle _obtenerValor = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String _valorRecuperado = (String)_obtenerValor.getSerializable("guardarValor");
```

these line throws error.

Comment: super.onBackPressed() calls finish() you don't need both

Comment: Thanks mate i only add the finish() method and it works,i thought that i need to call secod activity to back, im new in stackover flow but your answer are the correct

Comment: @user370305 oh yes i run again my app and crashes and my logcat shows an error in

Bundle _obtenerValor = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String _valorRecuperado = (String)_obtenerValor.getSerializable("guardarValor");

How can i avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `super.onBackPressed();` just write,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent _regresar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(_regresar);
    finish();  //don't forget to call this
}
```

Comment: I tried add to my code the finish(); line and i erased the super.onBackPressed(); but crashes over again

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the method `onBackPressed()`. Pressing the back button will close the `webView` activity, and `MainActivity2` will resume.